# How do I search emails on Honeycomb?

Tags: email, 3.0-honeycomb, search

I have multiple email accounts set up on Honeycomb. To my disappointment, I couldn't find any way to search my email. On my Froyo phone I can do this from the options menu. How can I do this on Honeycomb?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=en) app, there is a search icon (magnifying glass) that appears in the top right corner when you are within a mailbox. If you're using the stock, general Email app (with the yellow "@" icon) then I'm afraid there is no search function supported.